# Многооконость в JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Как в java сделать так, чтобы по нажатию кнопки открывалось окно 2, а окно 1 закрывалось? А точнее, как сделать так чтобы все это запускалось в public static void main(String args)? Бьюсь над этим уже не один день, пожалуйста скиньте полный пример того, как это сделать, а не фрагмент.

**Обновление**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Reader {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Form1 frame = new Form1();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1000, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    Form1 gg = new Form1();
gg.Menu();
    }
}
```

-

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Form1 extends JFrame{
JButton play;
 JLabel nick1;
JTextField nickform;
    String nick;
public void Menu() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    play = new JButton("Играть");
    nick1 = new JLabel("Введите ваш никнейм");
    nickform = new JTextField(20);
    add(nick1);
    add(nickform);
    add(play);
    }                                                                                              
}
```

Comment: Покажите, что у вас уже есть.

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос, а не добавляйте комментарии

Answer (score 0):

Нужно задать слушатель на кнопку. Как понимаю необходимо чтобы frame не было видно, так что можно просто задать visible(false)

```
JFrame form = new JFrame();
JFrame form2 = new JFrame();
JButton button = new JButton();
form.add(button);
button.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        form.setVisible(false);
        form2.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: у меня либо окно работает без элементов либо слушатель не понимает какое окно

Comment: @InfernO_O form.setVisible(false); form2.setVisible(true); делают видимым или скрывают определённые окна. Лучше всего исправь вопрос, и выложи туда полный код